# Android - how 3rd party libs for statistics work

Tags: android, google-analytics, statistics

I'm building a library for android and I want to collect statistics about my users who use the apps which contains the library.
Its important to note that this statistics are used to improve the experience of the users and the developers who use this lib know about collecting this information. (not any personal information, only information about the flow of the application).

On the one hand I don't want to make an HTTP call every time to collect this information but on the other hand I want to minimize the amount of data that should be lost.

My question is what is the best way to achieve this depends on Android platform, I think that I want to implement something similar to Google analytics but with custom data and wondering how this kind of libs are implemented.

Comment: In the end you have to send collected info to server. caching is one to store data and send them is batch but it will increase the payload size, to overcome it compression is an option.

Comment: How they cache it? I can think about internal storage file or SQLite table but afraid of many I/O operations. Do you know what is the best way to cache it so the app who use my lib won't affect by this I/O operations.

Comment: SQlite is the only option. putting too much data on shared preferences is not a good idea. Dont worry about too much IO operations its handled beautifully in Android. Just follow the best practices to do that.

Comment: And if I use SQLite in my library it should be affect it the developer also use an SQLite and delete/update? or it can be decoupled completely from the one of the developer?

Comment: there can do multiple databases. You can create for logging only, other developer will create of this own.

Answer (score 1):

On most Android devices that support Google Play Services (devices that have Google Play Store) analytics data is send over to Google Play services at the moment you call "send()". The service itself will batch and compress data from all apps and uploads the data with fewer requests then the actual send requests. Since the app that uses your library can itself be using analytics you should avoid setting up exception or auto screen view reporting as it will interfere with the app. If you configure one tracker from code your lib should have little impact on the app performance. If you expect heavy use you should consider sampling your tracker to something like 1% to minimize battery/network impact.